# Vue.js – Passing functions in array as a prop

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

#### NavigationBar.vue

The component `NavigationBar.vue` is used throughout my `Vue.js` application accepts the following props:

```
props: {
    title: String,
    actions: Array
}
```

This is the `NavigationBar` component:

[image: NavigationBar Component]

The component accepts the array to generate the action buttons on the right by using `v-for`. They are defined in the parent file and are different depending on the place in my application. If you click on a button, the specified function needs to be called.

#### Members.vue

Members.vue is the parent. Notice the component, actions and functions in there:

```
<template>
    <div>   
        <NavigationBar title='Members' actions="actionsArray" ></NavigationBar
    </div>  
</template>

<script>
import ...

export default {
  name: 'members',
  components: {
    NavigationBar
  },
  data () {
    return {
        actionsArray: [
            { btnText: 'Create', icon: 'mdi-plus-circle', function: 'createBtnClicked()' },
            { btnText: 'Edit', icon: 'mdi-pencil', function: 'editBtnClicked()' },
        ],
  }
  methods: {
    createBtnClicked() {
        // amazing things will happen here
    },
    editBtnClicked() {
        // it will be even greater when this button is clicked
    },
}

</script>
```

#### Problem:

I can't get the functions of the buttons to work as they should. Is passing the function as a prop even the right approach?

I would really appreciate some help! Thanks :)

Comment: Use slots for the buttons, that will also give you way more flexibility regarding the buttons layout

Comment: @minychillo Thanks. I decided to use slots because I came to a point where I needed exactly this flexibility and custom options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be passing strings and not actual functions.

Try the following:

```
data () {
    return {
      actionsArray: [
        { btnText: 'Create', icon: 'mdi-plus-circle', function: this.createBtnClicked },
        { btnText: 'Edit', icon: 'mdi-pencil', function: this.editBtnClicked },
      ],
}
```

Maybe consider declaring explicit [prop types](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Type-Checks) to have Vue check values assigned to props have the corect type.

Comment: wouldn't using function(){} be better than the arrow function in this case because ```this``` is bound to the parent and one of the limitations is arrow functions do not have its own bindings to ```this``` or ```super``` ??

Comment: There is no need to wrap the functions at all.  Just do `function: this.createBtnClicked`.  Notice the lack of parentheses on the end.

Comment: @gogo Thanks for your answer. However I now decided to use slots instead. They give me more flexibility and options in my app.